How to resolve threading issues with DbContext on .NET Core, EF Core
Got threads issue on EF Core 8.0, .NET 8, I got this issue how to overcome this?
Error:

A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.

internal sealed class CommandHandler : IRequestHandler<Command, string>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IValidator<Command> _validator;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _host;

    public CommandHandler(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IValidator<Command> validator, IWebHostEnvironment host)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _validator = validator;
        _host = host;
    }

    public async Task<string> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(request);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(validationResult.Errors);
        }

        using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var multiplePayment = request.PaymentRequest;
            var _paymentImageId = new List<int?>();
            var _paymentId = 0;
            var _imageName = new List<string?>();

            try
            {
                foreach (var item in multiplePayment)
                {
                    var getUserId = _dbContext.Auths
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == item.CreateBy, cancellationToken);

                    var generatedId = "Pay-" + GenerateId.MakeId();

                    #region image upload
                    if (item.ListOfImageBase64 is null || item.ListOfImageBase64.Count == 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var imageBase64 in item.ListOfImageBase64)
                        {
                            var createdBy = await _dbContext.Auths
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == item.CreateBy, cancellationToken);

                            string image = await Base64ToImage.UploadImageAsync(imageBase64, "Payments", createdBy.Name, WebRootUtility.GetWwwRootPath(_host));

                            var img = new Image()
                            {
                                ImageId = GenerateId.MakeId(),
                                GeneratedId = generatedId,
                                ImageName = Path.GetFileName(image),
                                ImageUrl = image,
                                ImageSize = new FileInfo(image).Length.ToString(),
                                ImageType = ".png",
                                CreatedTime = DateTime.Now
                            };

                            _dbContext.Images.Add(img);

                            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                            _imageName.Add(img.ImageName);

                            var paymentImage = new PaymentImage
                            {
                                ImageId = img.Id,
                                CreatedTime = DateTime.Now
                            };
                            _dbContext.PaymentImages.Add(paymentImage);

                            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                            _paymentImageId.Add(paymentImage.Id);
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion image upload

                    #region Payment
                    var checkCreateBy = await _dbContext.Auths
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == item.CreateBy, cancellationToken);

                    var payment = new Payment
                    {
                        PaymentId = generatedId,
                        CreateBy = item.CreateBy,
                        CreateByName = checkCreateBy.Name,
                        Source = item.Source,
                        Amount = item.Amount,
                        Method = item.Method,
                        DepositOption = item.DepositOption,
                        Date = DateTime.Now,
                        ChequeNoOrTrackingNo = item.ChequeNoOrTrackingNo,
                        Branch = item.Branch,
                        RoutingNo = item.RoutingNo,
                        Status = "Pending",
                        AuthId = checkCreateBy.Id,
                        CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
                    };

                    _dbContext.Payments.Add(payment);
                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    _paymentId = payment.Id;
                    #endregion Payment

                    #region OrderProcessList
                    foreach (var orderId in item.OrderIds)
                    {
                        var orderProcess = await _dbContext.OrderProcesses
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.OrderProcessId == orderId, cancellationToken);

                        var orderProcessList = new OrderProcessList
                        {
                            OrderProcessGeneratedId = orderProcess.OrderProcessId,
                            OrderProcessId = orderProcess.Id,
                            PaymentId = _paymentId,
                            CreatedTime = DateTime.Now
                        };
                        _dbContext.OrderProcessLists.Add(orderProcessList);
                        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    #endregion OrderProcessList

                    #region OrderProcess
                    foreach (var orderId in item.OrderIds)
                    {
                        var orderProcess = await _dbContext.OrderProcesses
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.OrderProcessId == orderId, cancellationToken);

                        var paymentAmount = await _dbContext.Payments
                            .Where(x => x.Id == _paymentId)
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                            .Select(x => x.Amount)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

                        var totalAmount = decimal.Parse(orderProcess.TotalAmount) + decimal.Parse(paymentAmount);

                        var isPartial = decimal.Parse(orderProcess.TotalAmount) >= totalAmount ? false : true;

                        if (isPartial)
                        {
                            orderProcess.IsFullPaid = true;
                            orderProcess.IsFullPaidDate = DateTime.Now;
                            orderProcess.IsPartial = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            orderProcess.IsPartial = true;
                        }

                        orderProcess.UpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;
                        _dbContext.OrderProcesses.Update(orderProcess);
                        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    #endregion OrderProcess

                    #region PaymentImage
                    var paymentImageIds = _paymentImageId;

                    foreach (var items in paymentImageIds)
                    {
                        var paymentImageUpdate = await _dbContext.PaymentImages
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == items, cancellationToken);

                        paymentImageUpdate.PaymentId = _paymentId;
                        paymentImageUpdate.UpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;
                        _dbContext.PaymentImages.Update(paymentImageUpdate);
                        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    #endregion PaymentImage
                }

                transaction.Commit();

                return "Payment created successfully.";
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                //foreach (var imageName in _imageName)
                //{
                //    string folderName = "Payments";
                //    string folderPath = Path.Combine(_host.WebRootPath, "Images", folderName, createBy.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty), imageName);
                //    if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                //    {
                //        Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
                //    }
                //}
                throw new ValidationException(ex.Errors);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                //foreach (var imageName in _imageName)
                //{
                //    string folderName = "Payments";
                //    string folderPath = Path.Combine(_host.WebRootPath, "Images", folderName, createBy.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty), imageName);
                //    if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                //    {
                //        Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
                //    }
                //}
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

How to resolve this issue?

First var getUserId = _dbContext.Auths.FirstOrDefaultAsync is not awaited.

By not using any of this code, it's fundamentally wrong and causes serious problems and scalability issues.. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It doesn't even open any connection until SaveChanges is called to persist all changes in a single transaction, and therefore doesn't need to be thread-safe. If you don't call it, nothing is saved so no explicit transaction is needed.

To quickly fix this method remove BeginTransaction, remove all calls to SaveChanges until the absolute last line, where you know that all the changes need to be persisted. Either make sure that CommandHandler is instantiated once per Handle call, or create the DbContext in Handle itself, perhaps with the help of a DbContextFactory. The operational unit here is Handle, so that's the scope of DbContext as well

Are you using MediatR? In that case CommandHandler is a singleton, while DbContext is a scoped service. The scope problem is identical to Using a scoped service in a BackgroundService or DbContext in Blazor Server. You must either specify your own scope smaller scope or use a DbContextFactory to create a DbContext in a single work unit

Yes, @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm using MediatR.

@livealvi apart from removing all the manual transactions and multiple SaveChanges, replace _dbContext.Auths.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == item.CreateBy and similar calls with var auths= await _dbContext.Auths.Where(x=>creators.Contains(x.UserId)).ToListAsync();. Requesting items one Row By Agonizing Row (RBAR is an actual term), you can get N times better performance by just loading them all at once. If you want to load related items do so through the entity relations (eg using eager loading with Include), not by trying to each row at a time.

thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, but https://imgur.com/a/rkMJPck - is it good?

@livealvi the getUserId and checkCreatedBy seem to contain the same full object.

No, because you're still calling SaveChanges in a loop. SaveChanges is effectively your Commit. You only call it once at the very end. I repeat, EF like all ORMs deals with objects and entities, not tables. It tries to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows.  If you want to add a Process item to an Order, you write thatOrder.Processes.Add(new Process(....)), you don't add it to the DbSet.

And instead of manually loading each object related to a payment, you can write _context.Payments.Include(p=>p.Auth).Include(p=>p.Order).ThenInclude(o=>o.Processes) etc to load the entire object graph at once

@PanagiotisKanavos Small detail: by default MediatR registers its classes as transient.

@GertArnold I looked this up first and I don't remember where I found they're singletons. If it was this SO question I read the wrong answer

To summarize: When having this kind of exception with your DbContext:

A second operation was started on this context instance before a
previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different
threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.

Most probably you forgot to await your async methods.

yes, that's correct @decius.
